# display database result array in Codeigniter Controller and Also Pass in View

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

How Can We Fetch specific details from result array in controller and also pass result array to view. below i have written the code that i am using to get data from database in codeigniter model and then including it in controller and also able to pass it to view and echo results there, but i want to get some specific column results ( Metatitle, Metadesc, Metakeywrd ) in controller, so i can set meta_title, meta_description, meta_keywords values in controller only and pass it to view head dynamically,

This is My Controller

```
<?php
class India extends CI_Controller {

     public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();       
    }

public function memberview()
    {
     $data['meta_title'] = '';
     $data['meta_description'] = '';
     $data['meta_keywords'] = '';
     $teamid = $this->uri->segment(6);      
     $data['view'] = 'region/india/team-member-view.php';
     $this->load->model('region/India_model');
     $data['team'] = $this->India_model->tmview($teamid);
     $data['teamlist'] = $this->India_model->teamlist();
     $this->load->view('region/layout', $data);


    }


}
?>
```

This is My Model

```
  <?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class India_model extends CI_Model{

    public function tmview($teamid){
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('ojiteam');
            $this->db->where("id",$teamid);
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query->result_array();

        }               
}
?>
```

Here in View i am fetching data like this, this is working properly but head parts meta tags is getting set at controller, there are multiple static pages for that meta tags getting set in controller file and for some dynamic pages meta tags have been saved into database column.

```
                  <?php        
                  foreach($team as $value){
                      };
    ?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en"/>
    <title><?php echo $meta_title; ?></title>
    <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $meta_description; ?>" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $meta_keywords; ?>" />
```

Comment: Where do you set the metatags?

Comment: i have updated my view @lbu

Comment: for some pages we set meta tags directly in controller and for posts and dynamic pages we get it saved into database.

Comment: Now that you have set the meta on the controller, and displayed it on the view, what seems to be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if i understood what you want but if i did i guess this is what you want ?

```
$team = $this->India_model->tmview($teamid);
 $data['meta_title'] = $team['meta_title'];
 $data['meta_description'] = $team['meta_description'];
 $data['meta_keywords'] = $team['meta_keywords'];
```

Comment: Yes I want the Same but i want array to be passed into view also, because there is multiple datas, that needs to be shown..

Comment: you load the view
$this->load->view('region/layout', $data);
and you can access to $data[] the same way you did !

Comment: No Sir, Its Not Working.

Comment: humm when you echo $data['meta_title'] what it says ? !!